# Microsoft Reciprocal License (Ms-RL)

Tags: open-source, licensing

Does anybody knows if I can use (opens source) software  components/controls, which are under the **Microsoft Reciprocal License (Ms-RL)**, in commercial projects ? 
Can anybody provide me a good and above all clear site with a overview of all **open source licences** and their restrictions ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FSF's [License List](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html) is one of the more comprehensive, and legally pedantic (in this case a good thing).

That list identifies the Ms-RL as a free-software copyleft license incompatible with the GPL.

If that description isn't enough to answer your question, then either the question is too broad for this sort of forum and will need find a more license oriented forum; or, the question is too specific to your situation (ie. you are probably attempting to loophole the license), and you will need to talk to a lawyer.